# Unable to Install from BIOS

Tags: grub2, bios, usb-installation

I have a new machine with no OS. Asus Prime motherboard. I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 from USB. I've done the same previously on an Asus Tuff motherboard.

From GRUB whether I try to install, or try without installing (even check disk for errors) I get the same set  ACPI messages, then complete loss of the screen.

- failure creating named object ae_already_exists
- ae_aml_package_limit
- pld due to previous error

[image]

BIOS has been updated.

I keep finding things about changing the kernel and adding

```
Apci=off
```

But I can't figure out where to do that.

Comment: What tool did you use to make the USB? Have you tried the USB on another computer?

Comment: I used Rufus and an iso from the ubuntu site - basically followed their directions exactly. Created it from my Lenovo Thinkpad running windows.    I've used the same key to install on another asus motherboard home build pc, as well as a microsoft surface pro4, and a lenovo desktop PC. Also i've run a temp "try ubuntu" from the think pad on it successfully today.